# Acumatica - Cannot Sort on Custom Unbound Generic Inquiry Column

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I've added a custom unbound field to the ***AR-Invoices and Memos*** generic inquiry in Acumatica (21.210.0030). When I click on the columns, the **Sort Ascending** and **Sort Descending** options are not showing.

Is there a setting that needs to be set to show these options, or can unbound fields not be sorted in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GIs are pushing the sorting into the SQL query behind the GI so correspondingly you can't sort based on the unbound fields as they don't exist in the database.

For example, below is the result of sorting desc by the invoice amount.

[image]